# preg_replace: remove tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I have a lot of option tags. I would like to remove the tags and get only the values.
This is the code:

```
<?php
$result = preg_replace('/<option value=\"\d+\"  >([A-Za-z0-9]+)<\/option>/', '$1', $result);
?>
```

I cannot use strip_tags, strip_tags output:

```
id="pesq_marca" class="select164" size="1" onchange="exibeModelosSelectpesq_marca(this.value, 'C','','');" >SelecioneAUDIBMWCHEVROLETCITROENFIATFORDGMCHONDAHYUNDAIJEEPKIA MOTORSMERCEDES-BENZMITSUBISHINISSANPEUGEOTRENAULTSUZUKITOYOTAVOLKSWAGENADAMOAGRALEALFA ROMEOASIA MOTORSBRMBUGGYCADILLACCBTCHAMONIXCHANACHERYCHRYSLERDAEWOODAIHATSUDKWDODGEEFFAENGESAENVEMOFERRARIGURGELHAFEIHUMMERINFINITIIVECO-FIATJAGUARJINBEIJPXLADALAND ROVERLEXUSLIFAN MOTORSLINCOLNLOBINIMAHINDRAMASERATIMAZDAMERCURYMINIMIURAMPNEVIO BRENDLERPORSCHEPROTOTIPOPUMASATURNSEATSHELBYSIMCASMARTSSANGYONGSUBARUTROLLERVOLAREVOLVOWAYWILLYS
```

With this code, I get the content of $result and a lot of trash. What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean the contents in the `<option>`-tag, or the value of the `value` attribute?

Comment: <option value="1">I WANT THIS STRING!</option>

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting all values from h1 tags using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299033/getting-all-values-from-h1-tags-using-php)

Comment: *(related)* [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Mark Baker, i cannot use strip_tags...

Comment: Also, do you want to *replace* or just *match* the node value?

Comment: The "trash" as you call it, you get when using strip_tags ist actually no trash. It's all values concatenated. That's the problem with strip_tags, it removes only the tags. I guess you got all option-tags in one line. if you'd insert a whitespace after each option, strip-tags would have been worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regex to read select form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224006/php-regex-to-read-select-form)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly your question has been asked before - see this post, it will definitely help you (including sample code):

[Stackoverflow: "php regex to read select form"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224006/php-regex-to-read-select-form)

The regex in question (from that post) is `preg_match_all( '@(<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/option>)@', $options, $arr);`

Comment: Couldn't find any information on how to mark a post as duplicate or on how to link posts in the FAQ. Also I don't see how this is not an answer to the question. (Sorry for being totally off-topic, but thanks for pointing out that this should be a comment)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('/<option.*?>([A-Za-z0-9]+)<\/option>/', '$1', $result);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same trash as before... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/<option [^>]*?>(.*)<\/option>/', $text, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```